# Get created_at field value in custom format(m/d/Y) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to show created order date using created_at field data in Laravel.

I have also try to get `created_at` date in my custom format `m/d/Y` but it's given the wrong date. I tried below code

```php
{{ date('m/d/Y',$order->created_at) }}
```

and it's given this result 10/01/48929

help me to get `created_at` date in my custom format

Comment: What value is in the database column `created_at` ??

Comment: What data type is the `crated_at` column

Comment: created_at : 1481906564000

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have found the solution. thank you for your reply

Comment: Post the solution as an answer, or this question is of no use to others

Answer (score 2):

All default date fields in Laravel are converted to Carbon objects (unless you tell them not to be) when retrieved from the database.
(http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

In your case you could just do:

```
{{ $order->created_at->format('m/d/Y') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

TimeStamp show with multiply by 1000 that why it's show 1481906564000.

My Model Code :

```
class BaseModel extends Model
{
   public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $value = date('U', strtotime($value));
    return $value * 1000;
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $value = date('U', strtotime($value));
    return $value * 1000;
}
}
```

Solution : `date('m/d/Y',($order->created_at)/1000)`